# Wordpress Cron Function using Cpanel

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, global, cpanel

I am writing a wordpress part of my site with php and am working on writing a cron that works within my wordpress site.  I don't want to use wordpress cron cause it only executes when people come to your page so I would like to use cpanel cron but be able to reference a cached object in wordpress but I haven't used cpanel cron and don't know how to reference it completely with php.  Can I make a cpanel cron job in php and have it run it hourly and cache the variable to be used by wordpress without wordpress running it everytime I load it when including the file in wordpress?  Do I have to include all files in php to have the variable of use or does global variable in php is accessable in all php files?  I'm kinda a newb when it comes to using cpanel, php, and wordpress.  I know this is a lot to ask but I am greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There's no such thing as "cpanel cron". There's only the cron system as provided by your server OS, and the cpanel interface to it. You can run whatever you want via cron. If you can get your cacheing script working from the command line, then it SHOULD work from within cron, as long as you make sure all paths and permissions are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to have everyone know who is looking to make their own cron from wordpress to look here.
http://wpdailybits.com/blog/replace-wordpress-cron-with-real-cron-job/74

I appreciate everyones help but this is a great overview I've found.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook it into Wordpress cron, then add a cron job in cPanel to run a command like this:

```
curl http://mysite.com/wp-cron.php
```

Then you get to write it using wp-cron, and you know wp-cron will have a chance to run regularly, even if nobody visits the site.

Comment: Ok these seems more like it.  So when using the wp_schedule_event to get it to the wordpress cron I can just hook the cpanel cron to the wp-cron.php file which will have it scheduled with the server.

Answer (score 0):

First, like Marc B says, there aren't different crons. Consider a cron as a scheduled job. You want it to run at different times/days. The CPANEL gives an interface for you to run the cron.

Now, about specifying crons through cpanel... if you're on a shared host, usually, the host **may** restrict access to command line. Of course it would also depend on the kind of hosting package given to you. This is why the CPANEL interface exists. It is a safer way of specifying your job. Otherwise, a beginner may experiment and give a bad command that may make the system vulnerable.

Now, here's how you should specify your cron job.

1. Create your PHP file that you need to run on schedule.
2. Go through the cpanel interface to create the cron job. I hope you can find it.
3. Now in the space provided, enter something like this example:

   `php -q /home/myhost/public_html/myfolder/mycronjob.php`

   In the above, example, you're saying run the cron with PHP. The path to the file is specified with reference to the location in the drive. Don't worry this path (`/home/myhost`) is not directly accessible by the public. This is how some hosts need you to specify the location. So you've got to check with your host or you may find a reference to it in the cpanel.
4. Now give the days/times to run it. There's a box or a group of boxes for this purpose. You may for example enter `0 5 * * *` and this will execute the job daily at 5:00AM.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Is there a way from to run a scheduled task by just writing php and not having to get into the cpanel interface?

Comment: yes, you can create the cron from the command line. But I believe you wanted to use the cpanel. And if you're asking if these methods can be avoided, then no. You must somehow tie it up with the OS. So if you're not keen in creating a cron, you can include the php code at some point like an admin login point or something. This way, every time the admin logs in, the code runs. But this is NOT a cron job.

Comment: I was thinking about trying to make reusable code and not have to tap into the cpanel if ever thinking about making a plugin.  That is where my question comes from.  Is it possible to have php tap into the cron of the server?  From what I understand from your answer you'll have to have access to the server user/password to schedule a cron task.

Comment: First, I thought I answered your question of running a cron independently without WP. But now it seems like your requirement is something else. Anyway, answering your new question, yes, crons need to have a proper server user. Otherwise you will have security issues.